# Max User Connection Error Occured

Tags: php, mysql

> User  already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connection

in mywebsite, Y this error coming, Anyone can help me.

Comment: Do you use persistent connections and do not close them properly?

Comment: Or raise the value of max_user_connections in my.cnf or alike and /etc/init.d/mysql restart.

Comment: @jacouh: IMHO in most cases this is just a workaround and does not solve the actual problem.

Comment: refer this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960954/how-to-prevent-exceeding-max-user-connections-upon-reloading-refreshing-page-mul

Comment: @ZombieHunter, ACK. Just list bad ideas here... The OP must check out.

Comment: Assuming you are using the mysql ext, don't use `mysql_pconnect` use `mysql_connect` instead. Or as other users have said make sure that you have used `mysql_close` before ending any scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't close your connections and get limit of connections? Close all your connection after using.